# SVN Got the repository going but what now?

Tags: svn

I am wanting to get into this SVN stuff, so i got a mac server and ran the following commands, as per a tutorial i am reading

```
cd /usr/local/repos
svnadmin create mynewwebsite
cd /tmp
svn co file:///usr/local/repos/mynewwebsite
cd mynewwebsite
svn mkdir tags branches trunk
svn ci -m "initial structure"
```

That works perfect, it has setup a new repository which i can see through my webserver with a bit more messing around.

Only thing is, im not sure what to do next ... I want to put all files and subdirs of my new website into it so i can start somewhere.

Could someone give me a quick rundown of how i can do that .... Im a bit lost with it.

Cheers,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

copy everything to the `trunk` and commit it.

```
cp /path/to/my/site trunk/
svn ci -m "initial commit"
```

Comment: After i do that, where will it put things? and can i delete the stuff out of /trunk/ ?

Comment: @Chris: After you do a commit - the data will be put into the central repository. Also you will have a local copy. And before you've learned svn enough - don't delete the site at his original location ;-)